# Do EKS Secrets are encrypted by default?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-secrets, amazon-kms

I was going by this update for EKS https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/03/amazon-eks-adds-envelope-encryption-for-secrets-with-aws-kms/ and this blog from AWS https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/using-eks-encryption-provider-support-for-defense-in-depth/.

This is a very cryptic line which never confirms whether EKS encrypts secrets or not by default

> In EKS, we operate the etcd volumes encrypted at disk-level using AWS-managed encryption keys.

I did understand that:-

- KMS with EKS will provide envelope encryption,like encrypting the DEK using CMK.
- But it never mentioned that if I don't use this feature ( of course KMS will cost ), does EKS encrypts data by default?

Because Kubernetes by default does not encrypt data . [Source](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/)

> Kubernetes Secrets are, by default, stored unencrypted in the API server's underlying data store (etcd). Anyone with API access can retrieve or modify a Secret, and so can anyone with access to etcd. Additionally, anyone who is authorized to create a Pod in a namespace can use that access to read any Secret in that namespace; this includes indirect access such as the ability to create a Deployment.

Comment: You can always verify it manually: just look into etcd contents.

Comment: I "could" have but I dont have privilege to access cluster, I need to propose this feature only after confirming considering cost and other factors and implement using terraform

Comment: Or you could spin a new EKS cluster under your own account ad-hoc, check it, and destroy, all in 10 minutes :-) PS: I don't really know the answer, if I needed it I'd do what I just mentioned :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it, the blog and update post by aws are very cryptic.

According to [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/clusters.html) and console :-

> All of the data stored by the etcd nodes and associated Amazon EBS volumes is encrypted using AWS KMS.

Using KMS with EKS is additional encryption or a better way of envelope encryption. It allows deploying a defense-in-depth strategy for Kubernetes applications by encrypting Kubernetes secrets with a KMS key that you define and manage.

[image]

Comment: I posted same thing, with the link, this information come from the info section as I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

short answer, yes it encrypted at rest

> The answer is yes, the data stored by etcd is encrypted at rest.

[Encrypt secrets at rest in etcd](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/263)

This encryption is in addition to the **EBS volume encryption that is enabled by default for all data (including secrets) that is stored in etcd as part of an EKS cluster**. so When encryption is enabled, then the secret store is encrypted form using KMS within `etcd`

The info tab contains further information
[image]

> AWS EKS is a managed Kubernetes offering. Kubernetes control plane components such as API Server, and **ETCD** are installed, managed, and upgraded by AWS. Hence you can neither see these components nor can exec into these components.

[image]

The below article also shows how to get cloud trail events when Kubernetes secrets are decrypted using KMS.

[eks-encryption](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/using-eks-encryption-provider-support-for-defense-in-depth/)

[Ensure AWS EKS cluster has secrets encryption enabled](https://docs.bridgecrew.io/docs/bc_aws_kubernetes_3)

Comment: `This encryption is in addition to the EBS volume encryption that is enabled by default for all data (including secrets) that is stored in etcd as part of an EKS cluster. `
Your answer contradicts your own point, this encryption is in addition which means it is already encrypted, I think its base64 if you are using only kubernetes, with EKS the etcd nodes are encrypted and  I guess with kms its extra encryption

Comment: `volume level - data level, so if someone gain access to volume that can not read but there is encription at volume level, but if someone gain access to etc then read because it just base64.`, this makes lot of sense, please include in your answer so that I can upvote

Comment: updated, the base 64 is actually for self-managed Kubernetes cluster

Comment: exactly what I meant that if you are using only self managed kubernetes cluster then  it not be encrypted but with EKS it is by default encrypted using AWS managed key

Comment: finally got something that worth to check https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/263, so the documentation really make confusing and other hand we can not do API call for etcd in eks to verify. so this issue makes it clear that's its encrypted